# How to convert a currency column of a table into a numeric column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

We need to make our schema support multiple currencies. So, using currency field is not a option. So, I am trying to convert currency column into numeric(12,2). I tried the following approaches:

```
ALTER TABLE lead ALTER COLUMN deal_size TYPE NUMERIC(12, 2);
ALTER TABLE lead ALTER COLUMN deal_size TYPE NUMERIC(12, 2) using deal_size::money::numeric(12,2);
```

each time I get the following error:

**ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 12, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^10**.

I verified that none of the values for this column in the table is more than $1,000,000

Answer (score 1):

I test the following in my PostgreSQL and works perfectly well. What version of PostgreSQL are you running?

```
create temp table lead (id serial not null primary key, deal_size money);
insert into lead (deal_size) select (random()*100000000)::numeric(14,4) from generate_series(1,10000) a;
ALTER TABLE lead ALTER COLUMN deal_size TYPE NUMERIC(12, 2);
```

You don't have values greater than a million. Have you tested for large negative values?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It's a silly mistake on my part. I didn't realize that there were a couple of large negative values(inserted as part of testing).